# Hibernate criteria adds more than one join with same alias

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Physical database model

[image]

Entity Model

[image]

I have 2 database tables A and B. In entity model A has three children A1, A2, A3. A2 and A3 have relation with B entity, so the relation is defined in these classes separately with the same property name.

I want to query A records with Hibernate criteria adding a restriction on bField. When an alias is added on bField, in a native query there are two joins with the same alias name. This causes `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` error.

```
criteria.createAlias("bField", "b");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.x", givenValue));
```

Resulting native query like this

```
select * from A a inner join B b on b.id=a.b_id inner join B b on b.id=a.b_id where b.x = ?;
```

In hibernate criteria documentation, I did not see any limitation on entity inheritance with same property field name. Is this normal behavior for Hibernate criteria?

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you create another, different alias?

Comment: If different alias is defined once in entity tree there is no problem.